# wp_enqueue_script includes plugin directory too soon in filepath

Tags: css, wordpress, path, content-management-system, filepath

```
public function setup(){
    //...
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_plugin_styles' ) );
}

function register_plugin_styles(){
    wp_register_style( 'dontwaste', JSC_DONT_WASTE . '/styles/dontwaste_styles.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dontwaste', false, null, null );
}
```

The JSC_DONT_WASTE is the path to the plugin directory, so JSC_DONT_WASTE . '/styles/dontwaste_styles.css'  returns the following:

```
/Applications/AMPPS/www/wpplugin/wp-content/plugins/dontwaste/styles/dontwaste_styles.css
```

and this is exactly the path I need to reach my css file.

But the code above returns this NOT FOUND error:

```
http://127.0.0.1/wpplugin/Applications/AMPPS/www/wpplugin/wp-content/plugins/dontwaste/styles/dontwaste_styles.css?ver=4.6.1 404 (Not Found)
```

You'll notice in the beginning there's a /wpplugin/ (the name of the plugin folder) right after the localhost. How do I get rid of that and get the path to work?

There's also the version number which even though I've set to NULL it still sets a version number.

Comment: Does it works with `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/styles/dontwaste_styles.css` instead of `JSC_DONT_WASTE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that makes sense.

Javascript and CSS **assets are loaded using their URI (or URL) and not path** on the server directories. As they're loaded on the frontend side. So it'll be something like `yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/js/your-asset.js`

So you can't use :

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )
```

You must use :

```
plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )
```

The first one is for files loaded in your plugin files (server side). Like a require_once. And the second one if for assets loaded on the user side.

Therefore, you can do something like :

```
// For the files called in your php : 
if ( ! defined( 'PLUGIN_DIR' ) ) {
    define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
}
// For the assets files loaded on the client side :
if ( ! defined( 'PLUGIN_ASSETS_URL' ) ) {
    define( 'PLUGIN_ASSETS_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/assets' );
}
```